# Email validation always firing on the client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Model:

```
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Required")> _
<EmailAddress(ErrorMessage:="Wrong Format")> _
Public Property LoginEmail As String
    Get
        Return _loginEmail
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _loginEmail = value
    End Set
End Property
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.LoginEmail, New With {.maxlength = 200})
```

It's working fine server-side, but if I turn on client-side, the 'Wrong Message' is always firing.

EDIT : I mean 'Wrong Format' which is EmailAddressAttribute error message.

Comment: What do you mean _'Wrong Message' always firing_? or do you mean its displaying 'Wrong Format' (i.e. its not valid)

Comment: Sorry I mean 'Wrong Format' which is EmailAddressAttribute's error message.

For example:

    warheat1990 (not pass),
    warheat1990@ (not pass),
    warheat1990@stackoverflow.com (should be valid but still it won't let me pass)

Comment: That suggests you not entering a valid email address (and if its empty, then you would be getting the "Required" error message)

Comment: Works fine for me `warheat1990@stackoverflow.com` passes. Sure you don't have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: nope, that's why I asked because it's working fine on server side.

Comment: Weird, perhaps post the html generated by the `TextBoxFor()` method.